# need help to getting started with cordova windows phone 10 application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, cordova-win10

I am cordova developer. I did application in windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1.

but now after windows phone upgrade to 10 i need to make my app compatible to `windows phone 10` also.

but i couldn't find any doc for making **windows phone 10** app in cordova documentation.

Can any one help in this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding Windows 10 support to your app is as easy as setting your Windows target platform version to 10.0 (`config.xml`):

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

[Cordova for Windows 10 docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/win8/win10-support.html)

[Visual Studio Tools For Apache Cordova-way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/30/introducing-the-windows-10-apache-cordova-platform.aspx)

Comment: But according to https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows they support windows 10 but not windows phone 10 can you give in more details.

Comment: [`cordova-windows`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/) also supports Windows 10 Mobile

Comment: Ok thanks they not specify about windowsphone 10 so i was confused.

Comment: In addition, Windows Phone 8.x apps will still work on Windows 10 Mobile phones